# SQLite Select with join from the same parent

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two simple tables:

Names:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | Name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | John Smith  |
|  2 | Joe Doe     |
+----+-------------+
```

Relations:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | ParentID | ChildID |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |       2 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

The table relation, Parent is Foreign Key to Names and Child is Foreign Key to Names.

Is there a way to SELECT and replace ParentID and ChildID with Name from Names where number matches Names.id?

Comment: Please provide the `.dump` from SQLite commandline tool for a suitable toy database.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Names (
    id   INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT
                       UNIQUE
                       NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR (255) COLLATE NOCASE
                       NOT NULL
                       UNIQUE
);`

`CREATE TABLE Relations (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                   UNIQUE
                   NOT NULL,
    Parent INTEGER NOT NULL
                   REFERENCES Names (id),
    Child  INTEGER REFERENCES Names (id) 
                   NOT NULL
);
`

Comment: I see there was a discrepancy, what I wrote in the question and what actually is in the **DB = Relations[id, Parent, Child]** not _Relations[id, ParentID, ChildID]_ but the question is still the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can join with the same table multiple times, as long as you give each instance a unique name:

```
SELECT Parent.Name,
       Child.Name
FROM Relations
JOIN Names AS Parent ON Relations.ParentID = Parent.ID
JOIN Names AS Child  ON Relations.ChildID  = Child.ID;
```

Alternatively, simply use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE id = Relations.ParentID) AS ParentName,
       (SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE id = Relations.ChildID ) AS ChildName
FROM Relations;
```

Comment: Cheers CL, second option worked the treat. I've just tried another way (from MySQL InnoDB):
`CREATE TABLE TestTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, ParentId INTEGER, ParentName VARCHAR (255), ChildId INTEGER, ChildName VARCHAR (255), FOREIGN KEY (ParentId, ParentName) REFERENCES Names (id, Name) ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (ChildId, ChildName) REFERENCES Names (id, Name) ON UPDATE CASCADE);`
but when I try to insert:
`INSERT INTO TestTable(ParentID, ParentName, ChildId, ChildName) values (1, "John Smith", 2, "Joe Doe")`
I have an error: `foreign key mismatch`

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button. And please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).